# How to send files to bluetooth in powershell

Tags: powershell

in windows explorer you can select a group of files, then right click, sendto -> bluetooth. I was wondering how you could do this with a powershell script.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe in .Net and C#?

Comment: C# is also fine

Comment: What have you searched for? What code have you tried? Post what you've tried and the errors you are getting. You can do just about anything via automation. Your post is really an option question not a PowerShell code issue, which is why were are here. A quick web search with your post's title, will give you a list of things to start with.